# Получить рабочую копию из локального репозитория SVN

Tags: svn, linux

Здравствуйте!

У меня есть svn репозиторий онлайн игры. Как получить рабочую копию этого репозитория?
Пробовал через svn co (локальный путь), но svn пытался подключится к http серверу, к которому доступа у меня нет.

Спасибо за любую помощь/подсказку. =)

Comment: [Читайте](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/edguide/chapter03.html)

(на всякий случай -- checkout).

Comment: Не могли бы вы описать полный процесс получения рабочей копии, допустим, из `/home/login/platform/`?)

Comment: Попробуй так: svn checkout /home/login/platform/ /home/login/newDirectory

Comment: @GlavPox2, почитал вопрос повнимательней.

Если правильно понял, Вам надо  излечь файлы из некой копии репозитория, которая лежит локально, а вовсе не из действующего svn репозитория?

Тогда Вам надо настроить свой svn сервер, который и будет извлекать данные из этой копии.

Comment: @avp, Да. 
Т.е получается, мне нужен или vps или на своём пк сделать сервер, подключить к директории svn, а потом извлечь через co, локально никак?(. Я не уверен, будет ли оно работать, так как в корень/.svn/entries (также во всех остальных каталогах/подкаталогах) уже прописана ссылка на svn репозиторий, к которому доступа нету.

Comment: @BogolyubskiyAlexey, svn: E125002: 'ПУТЬ' не является правильно сформированным URL.

Comment: @GlavPox2, никогда ничем подобным не занимался, но думаю, копаться надо в области переноса репозитория между svn серверами или восстановления репозитория на новом сервере.

Comment: Ясно, всем спасибо за помощь =)

Answer (score 3):

**Если** в `/home/login/platform/` находится *действительно* репозиторий (проверять dir-ом - у репы стандартная структура дерева), то

```
svn co file:///home/login/platform/
```

(читать про протокол `file:///` и оосбенности доступа по нему)